# multiple axis not starting at zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

I Darw a graph with mutliple axix, have several questios:

1. why the left y-axsis is not satrting from zero. (I mean the zero point
   is not at the begining of the y-axix).
2. I only want major grid for the x-axis (a major grid line for each week) but the code add a mjor
   grid for the y-axix also.
3. How can i add minor grid for y-axix (the red one (ax2))
4. i want to change the color for the x-axis labels (Dates) color to black

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   Hits= pd.read_excel("stackoverflow_example.xlsx", sheet_name="data")

   fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

   ax=fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
   ax2=fig.add_subplot(111, label="2", frame_on=False)

   ax.bar(Hits['Date'], Hits['Total'], width=0.35, color="b" )
   ax.set_ylabel('Hits', color="b",size=16)
   ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right') 
   ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors="b")

   ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors="b", rotation=45)
   ax.yaxis.tick_right()

   ax2.plot(Hits['weeks'], Hits['Cases'], linewidth= 3.5, color="Red")
   ax2.set_ylabel("Cases", color="Red",size=16)
   ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors="Red", size=16)
   ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

   major_ticks = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
   ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
   ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)

   plt.show()
   ```

My data

[[image: Data]

Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from zero, you can do that with 'ax2.set_ylim()'. After that, you can specify the axes for the grid. If the color is black, you can set color='k'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

ax=fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
ax2=fig.add_subplot(111, label="2", frame_on=False)

ax.bar(Hits['Date'], Hits['Total'], width=0.35, color="b" )
ax.set_ylabel('Hits', color="b",size=16)
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right') 
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors="b")

ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors="k", rotation=45)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

ax2.plot(Hits['weeks'], Hits['Cases'], linewidth= 3.5, color="Red")
ax2.set_ylabel("Cases", color="Red",size=16)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors="Red", size=16)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax2.set_ylim(0,62) # update
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', alpha=0.5) #update
ax2.grid(which='major', axis='y', alpha=0.5) # update

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ax2.grid(which='minor', axis='y', alpha=0.4) .. I tried to add this line but the minor grid didnot appear.

Comment: ax2.set_ylim(0,62) .. What if i want to number to be increased by 5 .... 0,5,10,15,20,...,65 ?

Comment: Have you copied and executed all the code? And `ax2.set_ylim(0,65)` should do it.

Comment: yes i exceuted the code and it works .. but what if I would be more flexible, forexample the y ticks increase with step=3 or 7

Comment: I added the line ax2.yaxis.set_ticks([0,3,6,....,66]) and it works .. is there another method?

Comment: You can import numpy as `np.arange(0,66,3)' and apply it to y-axis as well, since the third argument is the number of steps.